# Multiple phone number entries into one entry

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have `phone_numbers` table in which I store entry on `userid` and `phone_number_type` basis.

**Users data**

```
userid  ???   username     user_phone_no phone_number_type is_primary
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1       1     pranav       123456789     mobile            True
2       1     pranav       456789000     office            False
3       2     abc          11111111      home              True
4       2     abc          555566677     mobile            False
5       3     xyz          999555566     mobile            True
6       3     xyz          446662223     mobile            False
7       4     mmm          999555566     office            True
8       4     mmm          4466623       home              False
```

I made the following query:

```
SELECT userid, user_phone_no,
      ( 
        SELECT user_phone_no
          FROM phone_numbers
         WHERE phone_number_type ='mobile'
           AND is_primary IS False
         ORDER BY id ASC
         LIMIT 1 
      ) AS secondary_phone_no
  FROM phone_numbers
 WHERE phone_number_type ='mobile'
   AND is_primary IS True;
```

It gives me following result:

```
userid  user_phone_no  secondary_phone_no
------------------------------------------
 1      123456789      456789000  
 2      11111111       555566677  
 3      999555566      446662223  
 4      999555566      4466623
```

Expected result is:

```
---------------------------
userid  username mobile_no
---------------------------
 1      pranav    123456789
 2      abc       555566677
 3      xyz       999555566
```

For `mmm` result should not be there.

Is there any way to achieve expected result?

Answer (score 2):

Use This Query:

```
select 
   distinct on (userid) 
   userid, username, user_phone_no 
from phone_numbers 
where phone_number_type='mobile' order by userid, is_primary desc
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=67a67713ff4aaf1e60e99d7844d41c82)

Answer (score 2):

In terms of expected results you have nothing to do with `is_primary` column, and `secondary_phone_no`, just looking for ascendingly ordered records per each `username`, and want to give them fresh `userid` values. So consider using `ROW_NUMBER()` Analytic Function as

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY userid) AS userid, 
       username, user_phone_no AS mobile_no
  FROM 
  (
   SELECT p.*,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY userid) AS rn
     FROM phone_numbers p
    WHERE phone_number_type ='mobile'
  ) p
 WHERE rn = 1
 ORDER BY userid
```